# FullCalendar refresh interferes with the user's new selection

Tags: events, fullcalendar, refresh

I have already found [this answer][1], but I can't detect when the user start dragging for a new selection.

I need to refresh FullCalendar every 30 seconds, but without interfering with the user's activity.

Currently I have a bool in eventDragStart, eventDragStop, eventResizeStart, eventResizeStop events, but I can't find any event related to when the user start dragging in a blank area of the agenda view.
(In my calendar I have selectable: true, the user can create new events simply dragging in a blank area of the agenda view).

Any help is welcome! Thanks!

Comment: I presume you know about: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/select_callback/ - this callback runs when the user has dragged to make a selection. But it runs when the dragging finishes (and the user has chosen the area of the event), not when the dragging starts. When the dragging starts, there's not really any useful information available, since the user hasn't actually chosen anything yet, so that's probably why there's no callback for it.

Comment: Are you hoping to suspend your "refresh" action while the user is selecting an area? I think you'll struggle. I think maybe the best thing is to just test for conflicts/overlaps when the "select" callback runs, based on the latest set of events.

Comment: Yes, I would like to suspend the auto-refresh. The problem is that if the auto-refresh time is short (e.g. 10 seconds) the probability of interrupt the user selection is very high, then the effect is very annoying for the user experience...

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to refresh so often? Is it a very busy system? If not, it would probably be less problematic to refresh less often, but then when the user has made a selection, double-check against the server to ensure it doesn't conflict with anything added in the meantime

Comment: Yes, it's a multi-user very busy system. 
The page with the calendar is usually mantained open by the user to check real time situation.

Comment: I think you're stuck then. Unless you can examine the fullCalendar code, work out if there's some event that fires when the user starts to make a selection (I'd guess there's some sort of trigger, so that it knows to start highlighting the area) and see if you can hook into that somehow, even though it's not documented. I haven't read the source though, so I can't say how feasible that really is